# Template template argument deduction fails with Clang and MSVC, but succeeds with GCC

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdvector, template-templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, template <typename> typename U>
T get_max(U<T>& gr) {
    return *std::max_element(gr.begin(), gr.end());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c = {1, 2, 3};
    get_max(c);
}
```

While GCC [accepts](https://godbolt.org/z/4KibPN) the above code, Clang and MSVC [reject](https://godbolt.org/z/D_GGoq) it saying that argument (`std::vector`) has a different type (`std::vector` has two `template` parameters, but I introduced only one):

> ```
> <source>:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'get_max'
> get_max(c);
> ^~~~~~~
> <source>:7:3: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int]: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
> T get_max(U<T>& gr) { 
>   ^
> 1 error generated.
> Compiler returned: 1
> ```

Which compiler(s) is/are correct?

To my understanding, GCC is correct since the second `template` type is deducible (due to it being defaulted), but that might not be legal code due to actual signature mismatch.

Comment: *To my understanding, GCC is correct since the second template type is deducible (due to it being defaulted),* It's actually used to be the other way around.  A DR has been made and this has been fixed to allow it though.  Most likely the other compilers have not caught up.  I'm pretty sure there is a dupe, I'll try to find it..

Comment: @NathanOliver could you elaborate on the *DR*? I can't recall what that stands for. And if you find a duplicate I'll be more than grateful for the mark to read the answers there!

Comment: It's closed as a dupe now.  The answer has the DR(defect report) in it that you can read as well as a work around

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you!